# Simple Keynesian model of income determination

Tags: macroeconomics, keynesian-economics

When determining equilibrium, we take consumption equal to:

\begin{equation*}
C =a_{0} +a_{1} YD
\end{equation*}

where $\displaystyle a_{0}$ is the autonomous consumption or minimum consumption that would take place even in absence of income.
What could be the consequences on equilibrium income if the autonomous consumption $\displaystyle a_{0}$ was negative?

Comment: Side note: equations like this one are usually fitted to current levels of consumption and income (i.e. trillions of dollars). In such a regression it is possible for the intercept to be negative, but no one expects that to hold true if income theoretically fell to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see any way to have negative autonomous consumption. I believe autonomous consumption's extreme is zero if there's a kind of superheroes who don't need water, electricity and food to live and they save everything they earn. But in a case like this, there's  no reason for having aggregate supply at all as nobody will buy the goods in first place.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesn't seem like a plausible case in reality but like a few hypothetical cases if we consider hypothetically, autonomous consumption was ever negative how could it impact the equilibrium?

Comment: Also, when we talk about autonomous consumption we are assuming that the consumer s are borrowing to carry on their consumption and since it's a static model, can we assume that the consumers are lending at that particular time and thus, autonomous consumption is negative?

Comment: I suppose we talk about Aggregate Demand/Supply Equilibrium. In this case, $AD=C+I+G+NX$. If the economy is closed we just remove $NX$ from the formula. The autonomous consumption is just the constant term of $C$. If the constant decreases, then $AD$ shifts to the left (just look it mathematically since everything is linear).

Comment: If your economy is closed, the aggregate borrowing cannot exceed savings in first place. However, if your economy is open and you borrow to consume, then $MPC$ and/or $Y_d$ will increase, not autonomous consumption. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_consumption

Comment: Even at an autonomous consumption of zero, it would be difficult to make any simulations, unless you have government money to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consumption cannot be negative because of how it is defined. Consumption [measures people's spending](https://www.thebalance.com/components-of-gdp-explanation-formula-and-chart-3306015) on goods or services. Spending, like weight or distance cannot be negative.
2. If we forget about point 1 just as a thought experiment, the effect of negative $a_0$ on output would be just:

$$\frac{dY}{da_0 }= M\cdot\frac{da_0}{dt}$$

where $M$ is the multiplier (in most 101 textbook $M= \frac{1}{1-MPC}$ - where MPC is the marginal propensity to consume).

So if $a_0$ falls by 1% the output falls by $M\%$.

If $a_0$ would be sufficiently small it could even make output negative - but again that is nonsesical. Output, consumption, investment and government spending cannot be negative.